# Read the last line from the CSV file through Pandas

Tags: python

I am trying to read the last line from a CSV file stored in GCS.

My Code -

```
import pandas as pd
import gcsfs 
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-project') 
with fs.open('my-bucket/my_file.csv') as f:  
 file = pd.read_csv(f)  
 print(file.tail(1))
```

Output:

```
John       Doe 120 jefferson st. Riverside   NJ   08075
5   business-name Internal                 6       NaN  NaN     NaN
```

Public Sample CSV file -

```
John,Doe,120 jefferson st.,Riverside, NJ, 08075
Jack,McGinnis,220 hobo Av.,Phila, PA,09119
"John ""Da Man""",Repici,120 Jefferson St.,Riverside, NJ,08075
Stephen,Tyler,"7452 Terrace ""At the Plaza"" road",SomeTown,SD, 91234
,Blankman,,SomeTown, SD, 00298
"Joan ""the bone"", Anne",Jet,"9th, at Terrace plc",Desert City,CO,00123
business-name,Internal,6
```

I just want to get the last line - business-name,Internal,6 but that's not I'm getting. I'm not sure why tail(1) is not working.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Your code its just making that. The line "John       Doe 120 jefferson st. Riverside   NJ   08075" it's you dataframe header. You can solve that using pd.read_csv(..., header=None)

Answer (score 1):

The below pandas code should solve your issue. You can use the pandas `read_scv` function to get the csv data instead of reading the file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my-bucket/my_file.csv')
df.tail(1)
```

Comment: Hi mustafasencer, I tried using df = pd.read_csv('my-bucket/my_file.csv'), but it's not working in my GCP env. It throws error - IOError: [Errno 2] File my-bucket/my_file.csv does not exist: 'my-bucket/my_file.csv' - it's literally searching the file in the file system and not in the GCS bucket. Is there something I am missing? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

By looks of it the code is working correctly. By default it is printing header column. If you want to disable header printing use the follwing.

```html
file.tail(1).to_string(header=False))
```